# Django: How to add input elements to form as per input value

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms

I have a Django form coming from the below model:

```
class Ledger1(models.Model):
    ledger_name     = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    group1_name     = models.ForeignKey(Group1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='ledgergroups') 
    taxes           = (
        ('GST','GST'),
        ('Others','Others'),
        )
    tax_type        = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=taxes,default='GST',blank=True)
```

The modelform:

```
class Ledgerform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Ledger1

        fields = ('ledger_name', 'group1_Name','tax_type')

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):

        super(Ledgerform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ledger_name'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}
        self.fields['group1_name'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'select2_demo_2 form-control', 'placeholder':"Select Group",}
        self.fields['tax_type'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}
```

I want to create a form in such a way that the `tax_type` field will be hidden in the front-end and will only be visible if the User choses `tax` from the `ForeignKey` field `group1_name`.

The `tax` object is auto-created through a signal.

Not a pro in ajax,So facing some difficulties in solving the issue..

Any solution will be helpful in my learning process.

Thank you

Comment: This wouldn't be Ajax, it's just standard JavaScript.

Comment: In front end  in html form ? how is group name created is it dropdown ,multiselect or what ,can you show the form ?

Comment: Yes it is multiselect...User will have to select the group name from a dropdown list

Comment: Can you give me some link or some examples @DanielRoseman